# Swift closure in array becomes nil in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, swift3, objective-c-blocks

I created an objective-c method which will invoke a method via NSInvocation:

```
typedef void (^ScriptingEmptyBlock)();
typedef void (^ScriptingErrorBlock)(NSError *error);
- (void)scripting_execute:(NSString *)operation withParams:(nullable NSArray *)args {

    SEL selector = [self scripting_selectorForOperation:operation];
    Class class = [self class];
    NSMethodSignature *signature = [class instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];

    [invocation setSelector:selector];
    [invocation setTarget:self];
    for (int idx = 0; idx < args.count; idx ++) {
        id arg = args[idx];
        [invocation setArgument:&arg atIndex:idx + 2];

    }

    ScriptingEmptyBlock success = args[1];

    // Breakpoint added on next line to test for nil
    success(); // this is nil and would crash!
    // (lldb) po args.count
    // 3

    // (lldb) po success
    // Printing description of success:
    // (ScriptingEmptyBlock) success = 0x0000000000000000

    // (lldb) po args[1]
    // (Function)

    //[invocation getArgument:&success atIndex:2]; // also tried this and got nil as well
    [invocation invoke];

}
```

The method takes an "operation" which is translated into a selector by overriding `scripting_selectorForOperation:` in subclasses and then performs the invocation.

All of that works, except when the invoked method has block arguments they are nil, I added the test for nil I describe with comments, when attempting to read the closure from the array it will be nil.

Called like:

```
let successClosure: ScriptingEmptyBlock = {
                    print("Renamed product")
                }
let errorClosure: ScriptingErrorBlock = { error in
                    print("Failed to rename product: \(error)")
                }
let params:[Any] = [ "testName", successClosure, errorClosure]
object.scripting_execute (ScriptOperation.updateProductName.rawValue, withParams: params)
```

Why is closure becoming nil?

Answer (score 3):

`success` is *not* `nil` (in fact, `NSArray` cannot contain `nil`s). If you print it like `NSLog(@"%@", success);`, it will say `(Function)`, not `(null)`. And if you print its class like `NSLog(@"%@", [success class]);`, it will say `_SwiftValue`. Basically, it is a Swift value that is bridged into Objective-C.

The problem is that the object `success` points to is not an Objective-C block. It is a Swift closure, and Swift closures are not the same as Objective-C blocks. Trying to use invoke it as if it were an Objective-C block causes undefined behavior. `po` in the debugger prints it wrong probably because it is printing it assuming it were type `ScriptingEmptyBlock` (a block type). If you do `po (id) success`, it will print `(Function)`.

As to how you can explicitly put an Objective-C block into the array from Swift, the only way I figured out to do it something like:

```
let params:[Any] = [ "testName",
                     successClosure as (@convention(block) () -> Void)!,
                     errorClosure as (@convention(block) (NSError) -> Void)!]
object.scripting_execute (ScriptOperation.updateProductName.rawValue,
                          withParams: params)
```

I am not sure why it's necessary to put the function type inside a `!`, but it doesn't seem to work otherwise. Maybe someone else can find a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I must admit that I don't fully understand why this is happening, but as far as I can tell this has nothing to do with using `NSInvocation` and would happen even if we just passed a Swift closure to an Objective-C function via a parameter of type `id`.  Passing an Objective-C block via `id` works just fine, not sure why: Swift closures are supposed to be compatible with Objective-C blocks.  As you know, elements of `NSArray` are of type `id`, so any Objective-C object can be an array element.

To work around this problem of accessing a Swift closure passed via `id` in Objective-C one can introduce a wrapper class.

```
// In a header:
@interface EmptyBlockWrapper : NSObject
@property EmptyBlock _blk;
@end

// In an implementation file (just an empty implementation):
@implementation EmptyBlockWrapper

@end
```

Then we can use a wrapper instance instead of a block as an array element in Swift:

```
let myBlock : EmptyBlock = {
    print("In Swift EmptyBlock...")
}

let myBlockWrapper = EmptyBlockWrapper()
myBlockWrapper._blk = myBlock
```

In an Objective-C method we can call it as follows, assuming `args` is `NSArray *`:

```
EmptyBlockWrapper * emptyBlockWrapper = args[1];
emptyBlockWrapper._blk();
```

Hopefully this is helpful.  Of course, this is just a simplified example to give you an idea; this could be made much fancier.