# Invoke Swift closure in Objective-C via `id`

Tags: objective-c, swift, closures, block

This question has been inspired by this one: [Swift closure in array becomes nil in Objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44684601/swift-closure-in-array-becomes-nil-in-objective-c), which I answered with a workaround using a wrapper class, but I'm still curious as to why one can't call, in Objective-C, a Swift closure passed via `id`.  A simple example follows.

Objective-C code:

```
// In a header
typedef void (^EmptyBlock)();

@interface MyClassOC : NSObject

-(void)invoke:(id)blk;

@end

// In an implementation (.m) file
@implementation MyClassOC
-(void)invoke:(id)blk {
    EmptyBlock emptyBlock = blk;
    emptyBlock();
}
@end
```

No problem providing an Objective-C block:

```
EmptyBlock block = ^{ puts("In OC empty block..."); };
MyClassOC * myClassOC = [[MyClassOC alloc] init];
[myClassOC invoke:block];
```

However, the Objective-C code in `invoke...` can't call a Swift closure passed in via `id`:

```
let myClassOC = MyClassOC()

let myBlock : EmptyBlock = {
    print("In Swift EmptyBlock...")
}

myClassOC.invoke(myBlock)
```

I end up with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on this line:

```
   EmptyBlock emptyBlock = blk;
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is probably the support introduced in Swift 3 for any Swift type to be represented as an opaque object of `id` type in Objective-C. Read *Swift Value Types in Objective-C* in [this Apple blog post](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=39) for details. In that you will see that Swift types are passed as `_SwiftValue *` when the parameter type is `id`, this is an opaque type.

The argued benefit of this approach is that Swift value types can be stored in Objective-C collections; however the disadvantage is that you cannot convert to an Objective-C compatible value on the Objective-C side. Debug your code and you'll see the block is being passed as a `_SwiftValue *` and not an Objective-C block type.

Declare the `bak` parameter to have `EmptyBlock` type and your code works.

HTH

Comment: Thank you, the explanation makes sense.  I know changing the type from `id` to `EmptyBock` works.  But is there a way to call a block in Objective-C if it has been passed in from Swift as `id`?  For example, what if an Objective-C method received the `id` as part of `NSArray`?  Interestingly, in this case `EmptyBlock` is an Objective-C type bridged into Swift, with a Swift closure assigned to a variable of that type, yet Objective-C seems to treat it as a Swift value type.

Comment: `_SwiftValue` is an *opaque* type and AFAIK Apple have chosen not to provide Objective-C methods to determine what it wraps and to access the wrapped value. The `NSArray` case you raise *should* be solvable using lightweight generics on the Objective-C side. It is "should" as my attempt to confirm it caused the Swift 3.1 compiler to crash (*not* the compiled program).

Answer (score 2):

Because Swift closures and Objective-C blocks are not the same things. Swift automatically converts a closure to an Objective-C block if they see that you are calling a method with an Objective-C block type, but it doesn't do that otherwise. And as CRD's answer mentions, in Swift 3 any Swift value can be represented as an Objective-C object, so even though it sees that it expects an Objective-C object, it still doesn't know you want an Objective-C block because a Swift closure can still be bridged to an opaque object.

The only way I figured out to pass it from Swift and work is something like:

```
myClassOC.invoke(myBlock as @convention(block) () -> Void)
```

Comment: According to https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html, section Closures, `EmptyBlock` should have been imported into Swift with the block calling convention.  However, for some reason we still have to cast as shown or alternatively use `typealias MyEmptyBlock = (@convention(block) ()->Void)` and then `let myBlock : MyEmptyBlock =...`.