# Swift closure as parameter pass to objective-c

Tags: swift, closures, block

I want to pass a closure to objective-c class by a Dictionary.
How to implement it?

In my swift class:

```
let printTest: (_ para: String)->Void = { word  in
    print(word)
}

var dic = ["element":printTest]
var vc = CustomViewController()
vc.dict = dic
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

How can i get closure from dict in my objective-c class ? and how to called printTest?

Comment: Where is the passing to Objective-C in that code?

Comment: CustomViewController which has an dict parameter implemented by objc

Comment: Please show the definition of `CustomViewController` including the declaration of `dic`.

Comment: The thing is, passing a dictionary to Objective-C does _not_ cross the bridge for the dictionary's values.

Comment: Thanks both of you，Finally I get it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44750677/1707739

Comment: Correct. Write `let printTest: (@convention(block) (_ para: String)->Void)? = { word  in` ... The block can then be retrieved within Objective-C, and you can invoke it like a function. I do not understand why the `?` is needed.

Comment: @matt  I found that '?' or '!' is needed,If I remove it, printTest called failed.Maybe @convention(block)  require this. I don't know.

Comment: "If I remove it, printTest called failed" I know that. But I don't know why. :)